# Repeating background service using Alarm Manager

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, background-service

Currently I'm working on a new android project which uses background service. Because android version >=Oreo kills service automatically. So i use AlarmManager. I need to display a notification on exact time. Time for notification is setted in shared preferences.
My Alarm handler is following

```
class AlarmHandler {
    private Context context;
    AlarmHandler(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    void setAlarmManager(){
        Intent intent=new Intent(context,NotificationService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,2,intent,0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager= (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if(alarmManager!=null){
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,5000,60000,pendingIntent);
        }
    }
    void cancelAlarmManager(){
        Intent intent=new Intent(context,NotificationService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,2,intent,0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager= (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if(alarmManager!=null){
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

My Notification service is following

```
public class NotificationService extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String t1=timeFromsharedPreferences("t1");
        String t2=timeFromsharedPreferences("t2");
        String systemTime=getCurrentTime();
        if(systemTime.equals(t1)){
            notify();
        }else if(systemTime.equals(t2)){
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

I start AlarmHandler using following code

```
AlarmHandler alarmHandler=new AlarmHandler(this);
alarmHandler.cancelAlarmManager();
alarmHandler.setAlarmManager();
```

I also register the broad cast receiver as following

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationService" android:enabled="true" />
```

My problem is some times it's skipping my notification. Time is sheduled for 10:00 pm and 7:00 am. Notification on 10 pm is recieved (Note that i'm using phone at 10:00 pm or used minutes before 10:00 pm). But notification on 7:00 am is not receiving all time. Also note that i need notification on every day at same times. Please help me.

Comment: Tell me if any other method exists

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a repeating exact alarm. If you need it to repeat at exact intervals, you need to set an exact alarm at the 1st interval, then re-arm the alarm when it fires so it is armed for the next interval, and keep repeating that process.

Edit:

you need to do something like this

```
1.- compute delta in millis to next interval
2.- set exact alarm to fire in delta millis
3.- when the alarm fires, handle the event and then go to step 1
```